# Tableau Server 9.2 different version from workbook 9.3

Tags: tableau-api

I currently have a Tableau workbook that was built using Tableau 9.3.2, build 9300.16.0520.1152 for Windows.  However, the server uses Tableau 9.2, so I get an error when uploading it due to the difference in Tableau version.

So, I decided to install Tableau 9.2 on my client computer.  Yet when I attempt to open the .twb or .twbx file in Tableau, I receive the following error message.

> This file was created by a newer version of Tableau. Please contact
>   Tableau Software to upgrade your version.

My attempted solution to this so far is to open the .twb file in notepad, since it shows the xml code whereas .twbx appears to be zipped.  This solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298047/after-upgrading-tableau-to-9-2-i-am-unable-to-publish-workbooks-in-the-tableau).  I have been going through the file and changing `9.3` to `9.2` as well as the build number.  However, there are many lines similar to and including the following line:

```
 <statistic aggregation='StdevP' datatype='real'>213329.37572435648</statistic>
```

Notice the `9.3` in the >21332**9.3**7572435648<

I am unsure if this is something that I should also substitute `9.3` for `9.2` in or if it is a mere coincidence.  I am inclined to think it isn't because of the frequency that the `9.3` occurs.

My question is, should I replace it in the above line and similar lines?  If so, will there be any discrepancies between the .twb file modified for 9.2 and the original 9.3 file?  Otherwise, is there a more reliable method of downgrading the workbook?

Addendum: Upgrading the server is not an option

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved via the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298047/after-upgrading-tableau-to-9-2-i-am-unable-to-publish-workbooks-in-the-tableau) by @vk1011.  It worked without changing the lines similar to:

```
 <statistic aggregation='StdevP' datatype='real'>213329.37572435648</statistic>
```

There were no discrepancies between the original 9.3 file and the newly ported 9.2 file.